# Call action tag in method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

I want log in through gmail on my website and I am using google API for that, basically the problem is that when the google sign-in button is callback method is called(`onSignIn()`), than i want to add the action tag with in the method for implementing the slim behaviour for routing.

The whole did i successfully implemented when a form is available(by providing the action in form tag), so I am little bit confused how can I do that.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">
```

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

  alert(profile.getEmail());

  // here i want to call the route.php
}
```

Call action tag behaviour in method

Comment: You can `get` route.php with jQuery as explained here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: yeah i tried but its is not working in my case

Comment: not working why?

Comment: i don't know...i tried to put var_dump().. but nothing is print